# How to solve TimeOut Exception when save data to Azure from Xamarin.forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms

I am getting Exception "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess"

When I want to store single text to Azure.

Initially its working fine but I have created a new app service on Azure and update service url. then its not working properly.
Now I have two App Service and using common DB and DB server.

Log:
[0:] System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00026] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>d__63.MoveNext () [0x00528] in <35658e59c86d40bdbb2ef0bb34b4f0c7>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+d__49.MoveNext () [0x000ca] in <35658e59c86d40bdbb2ef0bb34b4f0c7>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__26.MoveNext () [0x00076] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+d__18.MoveNext () [0x000f0] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<>c__DisplayClass23_0+<<InsertAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x000c1] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+d__43.MoveNext () [0x0007f] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<InsertAsync>d__23.MoveNext () [0x0011f] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1+<TransformHttpException>d__31[T].MoveNext () [0x00066] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1+<InsertAsync>d__6[T].MoveNext () [0x000f1] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable`1+d__5[T].MoveNext () [0x00069] in <24dbefba60fd49f4b193cdf58abf3290>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0001a] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <657aa8fea4454dc898a9e5f379c58734>:0 
  at App4.TodoItemManager+d__13.MoveNext () [0x00058] in c:\users\parmendra\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App4\App4\App4\TodoItemManager.cs:102 
Thread finished:  #18

Comment: did it ever work with the db in azure or it worked for a local db only ?. also add the stack trace if any to have more idea about the error.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Parmendrakumar/3d59ec5d6a497ebb507c8bccae0adfb0

Comment: yes implement only Azure db

Comment: check if the target table available  is available in the azure db, check if azure firewall allows ip address of the machine that you are testing this.

Comment: Do you run it locally or on Azure? If possible, please add the demo code and add the which line get the error. Also as Aravind mentioned that please also check the firewall setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this... :)  Both service are conflict I have created new one and its working fine